# QGIS kml export with symbols

Tags: qgis, kml, symbology

I'm new in qgis and I need some help.

I'm trying to export a specific layer with defined some points using different symbols.

The exported kml file will discard the symbol type layout.
[image]

This is the resulting vision of the kml file:

[image]

Anyway if I will use ony a simple symbol will the symbol layout will not exported by qgis.

Answer (score 2):

Assuming that you want to open your final KML file in QGIS (?), you would have two solutions :

- Styling your layer with data-defined values ;
- Exporting two different layers and then applying them different styles.

Comment: I want to open the KML from Google Earth or other online maps tools (like http://map.geo.admin.ch).

I'm unable to export KML with the Style of my points. When imported, the KML will show all data with the default symbol.

Thanks for help!